# Loop Through 1st cell of each column in used range Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have some sample data in a sheet, I want to get headers of each column in used range, Here is the sample

[image]

I never know the exact number of columns used, I need to get all headers (**Customers**, **Managers**, **Managers-2**....)from this sheet to show it to user.

I can loop through each cell in a used range like

```
For Each cell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).UsedRange

Next
```

but how can I loop though each column, and only read values from their 1st cell? as number of these lists can be one or more than one.

Comment: It's the same as row 1 of the used range.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav: yes Exactly, 1st row of Used range

Comment: that's the answer, usedrange.rows(1)

Comment: For the `For Each` loop you should use `UsedRange.Rows(1).Cells`

Comment: @Fratyx: your answer is worth an answer, so that Adil can check it as the answer.

Comment: @Fratyx: Thanks, It worked :) you can post your solution as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your code by this one iterate over the first row of used range:

```
For Each cell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).UsedRange.Rows(1).Cells
   ...
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'Get a 2D array of header values

Dim aHeaders() As Variant

aHeaders = Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows(1).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your data quality. Come across this numerous times.

If your headers are consistent, then you just need to resize to the first row. Something like:

```
Dim r as range, r1 as range

Set r = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Resize(1)
```

Then do a for each for the r range.

```
 For Each r1 in r

 Next
```

You could also use an integer variable....

```
 Dim i as integer
 For I = 1 to r.Count

 Next
```